# while(true) iteration runs out RAM memory

Tags: c, heap-memory, ram

I am trying to figure out this issue:
I tried to run this two easy codes

```
int main(void) {
    while(1) {
       printf("Do nothing\n");
    }
   return 0;
}
```

When I execute it my memory RAM runs out.
Then I tried this variation:

```
int main(void) {
    while(1) {
       // do nothing
    }
   return 0;
}
```

And on that case my code runs without running out RAM.
My question is: why does it happen? Does `printf` occupied memory or maybe I am overloading `stdout`? **Thanks!**

Comment: "When I execute it my memory RAM runs out" How did you measure this?

Comment: Using system monitor

Comment: Do you perhaps have unlimited scrollback in your terminal?

Comment: Also please remove either the C or C++ tag - they are different languages.

Comment: Yes, probabily. I am using an IDE terminal as output. @ColonelThirtyTwo, done it

Comment: Thanks! I have solved it: it was a terminal issue. Just to clearify: it was about stdout issue? It went on overloaded?

Comment: What happens if you pipe the output to null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the terminal that is running out of memory, then yes, the terminal isn't clearing the stdout properly.

If it's the program itself running out of memory, then i don't know actually.

Comment: Thanks! I have solved it: it was a terminal issue. Just to clearify: it was about stdout issue? It went on overloaded?

Comment: Yea so the terminal takes the program's stdout pipe data (also stderr data if it exists) and it will store it in memory so it can be viewed by the user, most terminals clear it after 1000 to 10,000 lines or a certain number of characters, but you can turn that off if you need to.

Comment: stdout itself is just how the program outputs data. The issue is the terminal not clearing the buffer, i hope my explanation is clear!

Comment: Now it is clear! Thanks!!!

Comment: Imagine how many times per second you print something

Answer (score 1):

With such a simple program I cannot see any reason it would itself be using up memory. Only stack memory is temporarily used but is returned each cycle of the while loop. The clue is that one program is outputting to stdout and one is not.

Therefore it seems that something is buffering the output from the program. The terminal history buffer, an IDE buffer or something similar that records  stdout.

Comment: No stack memory is used at each iteration of the while loop, just the call to printf's return address which doesn't need to even go to the stack (the printf() parameter, or the return address, it depends on the processor that they go on the stack ---they will probably go, but that's architecture dependant)  No automatic variables are declared (even if they do no need to adjust the stack is needed inside the loop)  Neither memory leak is performed in the loop, nor recursive call.